# Why do I get Invalid Object Name for a SQL Server table, when the object is valid?

Tags: c#, sql, object

I am trying to execute an SQL query at runtime:

```
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader reader;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Books_in_Storage WHERE author = 'myself'";
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = connection;
        connection.Open();
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        connection.Close();
```

Execution reaches `reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();` and gives  me the error:

> Invalid object name `dbo.Books in Storage`.

If I look at my SQL Server Object Explorer, I can see that `dbo.Books in Storage` is present:
[image]

Why is this happening?

Comment: `Books in Storage` and `Books_in_Storage` are not the same. Preferably, rename the table not to use spaces.

Comment: This is just one of the roughly 3,980,437 reasons not to use underscore or (especially) spaces in table and object names.

Comment: [dbo.Books_in_Storage] ? - but also avoid underscores

Comment: Also, "in storage" seems a red flag to me. They are probably just "Books" with perhaps a field (or related field or calculation) to indicate whether or not they are in storage.

Comment: It seems that you have created a database with AttachDbFileName but now you are not using anymore that property in your connection string and you don't specify any database to connect to. So your query works against the master database where there is no table with that name. (Of course the advices to not have tables with spaces are absolutely right)

Comment: @Steve I think you are correct. I have just tried the same with another table that doesn't have spaces in its name and I have the same issue.

Comment: I suggest to always have the "Database=LogicalDatabaseName;" in your connectionstring when you work with LocalDb

Comment: On the subject of square brackets, `[dbo.Books in Storage]` won't work. `[dbo].[Books in Storage]` or `dbo.[Books in Storage]` is what you'd need.

Comment: Multiple issues here as people have noted, spaces are not underscores, you aren't specifying the database where the table resides, also would highly recommend `Using` so your objects are disposed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can query a table with spaces using the [] as shown below, however, **it is not normal** to include spaces when choosing your database table names.

```
SELECT * FROM [table name]
```